# Help solving thermal runaway in voltage follower circuit

Tags: amplifier, bjt, npn, common-collector

I'm trying to build a circuit to drive a heating element. In testing a portion of the circuit, I've noticed what looks like some kind of thermal runaway in the Darlington transistor I'm using, but I'm struggling to understand how this is possible.

[image]

At first, the voltage at the emitter follows the base quite accurately. As the transistor heats up, the voltage at the emitter runs away to ~22V, and high current. I'm struggling to understand how this is possible - how is the BJT still conducting when there is no forward bias? - and how to fix the problem.
(The 2N6037 seems to be rated to 40W - see attached)

The op-amp portion is for voltage amplification - I apply a signal of 0-3.3V at 3, and am hoping for approx 0-22V at the darlington emitter.

I've tried isolating just the voltage follower circuit and have had the same problem.

[image]

*(edited to fix missing wire in schematic)*

Comment: The transistor is rated to 40 W *with a heatsink to keep* Tj *below* 150 °C. Note that the 40 W is with Tc at 25 °C.

Comment: If this is a heating element then you should really be using PWM with a MOSFET, that will be a lot more efficient. If you did not cool your transistor sufficiently with a large enough heat sink, what most likely happened is it burned and became a short circuit.

Comment: check the "safe operating area" charts on the trans? look up "secondary breakdown". consider momentary conditions...

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Funny, i though the transistor would be fried, but it seems to behave normally otherwise. Probably safer to get rid of it anyway - I see now that the temperature condition is definitely not being maintained. I will try the PWM solution instead, with components more resistant to high temperatures. Thank you!